# How to explicitly pass schema name in @GenericGenerator?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to generate an auto-increment string using @GeneratedValue and @GenericGenerator. Everything is working fine except it is using my default schema. How to use a specific schema with @GenericGenerator

```
public class PMEntity {
 @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy =  GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PNO_SEQ")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "PNO_SEQ", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "sequence_name",value = "PNO_SEQ"),
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1"),
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "1")
            })
    @Column(name = "CPNO")
    private String plyNumber;
}
```

Comment: I have already set a default schema. If I provide schema as a prefix it will become X.SCHEMA.PNO_SEQ.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define your entity schema before its declaration. Ex:

```
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE_NAME", schema = "MY_SCHEMA")
public class PMEntity {}
```

Comment: This does not work, not sure why +1 was given. If table is in schema A, and the current Entity manager is configured with default schema B. Then the  @GenericGenerator will look into the schema B which is the default schema of the Entity manager.

Answer (score 0):

Billy's answer did not work for me. Here is what worked for:

```
  @Id
  @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "sequence-identity", parameters = {
@Parameter(name = "sequence", value = "SCHEMA.PNO_SEQ")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1"),
@org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "1")
})
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")    
@Column(name = "CPNO")
private String plyNumber
```